# How to iterate through a recursive class in Jython?

Tags: python, recursion, iteration, jython

I've created a class in Jython which accepts an object at its top level, then recursively iterates through all child objects (from an external system) to effectively give me an embedded tree of objects.  From this, I can use a similar technique to list the relevant attributes of the children, simply using recursion.

However, I now need a method of iterating through this tree from a calling program, where I can use a for loop which will recursively iterate through all the children, and I can't get my head round this!

Any pointers, please?

Code:

```
class DepotGroup():

    def __init__(self, jli, groupName, groupFQPath, groupID, parentID=0):
        self.logger = clog.CoBaLogging("Class:DepotGroup")
        self._jli = jli
        self.name = groupName
        self.fullyQualifiedPath = groupFQPath
        self.ID = groupID
        self.parentID = parentID

        # Create and populate the children[] list
        self.children = []
        self._FindChildren()

        # Now do the same for Depot Objects
        self.depotObjects = []
        self._FindDepotObjects()

        return


    def AddChild(self, childGroupName, childGroupFQPath, childGroupID):
        child = DepotGroup(self._jli, childGroupName, childGroupFQPath, childGroupID, self.ID)
        self.children.append(child)

        return

    def _FindChildren(self):
        (ok, childList) = self._jli.cliCall("Group", "findAllByParentGroup", DEPOT_GROUP, self.ID)
        if not ok:
            raise EnvironmentError("BLCLI call 'Group.findAllByParentGroup()' failed")

        for child in childList:
            (ok, groupPath) = self._jli.cliCall("Group", "getStringPathToGroup", child.groupId)
            if not ok:
                raise EnvironmentError("BLCLI call 'Group.getStringPathToGroup()' failed")
            self.AddChild(child.name, groupPath[5:], child.groupId)

        return

    def _FindDepotObjects(self):
        (ok, objList) = self._jli.cliCall("DepotObject", "findAllByGroup", self.ID, False)
        if not ok:
            raise EnvironmentError("BLCLI call 'DepotObject.findAllByGroup()' failed")

        for depotObj in objList:
            self.depotObjects.append(DepotObject(depotObj.name, depotObj.objectId, depotObj.DBKey, depotObj.objectTypeId))

        return

    def __list(self, indent=""):
        if indent=="":
            print "%s" % self.fullyQualifiedPath
        else:
            print "%s/%s" % (indent, self.name)

        childIndent = "%s    " % indent
        for child in self.children:
            child.__list(childIndent)

        for depotObj in self.depotObjects:
            flag = ""
            if depotObj.IsBLPackage():
                flag = "*"

            print "%s  - %s %s" % (indent, depotObj.name, flag)

        if indent=="":
            print "\n\n[Note: '*' indicates a BLPackages]\n"

        return

    def list(self):
        self.__list()
        return

    def __repr__(self):
        thisNode = {'Name': self.name, 'FQPath': self.fullyQualifiedPath, 'GroupID': self.ID, 'Children': []}
        for child in self.children:
            thisNode['Children'].append(child)

        return repr(thisNode)

    def __str__(self):
        retVal = ""
        retVal += "Name       : %s" % self.name
        retVal += "\nFQPath     : %s" % self.fullyQualifiedPath
        retVal += "\nGroup ID   : %s" % str(self.ID)
        retVal += "\n# Children : %d" % len(self.children)

        return retVal

    def __len__(self):
        totalLen = len(self.children)

        for child in self.children:
            totalLen += len(child)

        return totalLen




class DepotObject():

    def __init__(self, objName, objID, objDBKey, objType):
        self.name = objName
        self.ID = objID
        self.DBKey = objDBKey
        self.type = objType

    def IsBLPackage(self):
        return (self.type == BLPACKAGE)
```

Comment: Code please? At first sight I think you need a recursive generator.